# Namespaces and objective C

Tags: objective-c

In c# I use namespaces in java I use packages.  Is there a way to keep classnames short in objective c?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objective-C only has one, single global namespace. That is why you often see classes called `SBJsonParser`, so that the class name doesn't collide with other `JsonParser`s out there.

The general recommendation I have seen is to prefix your classes with either your initials or with a few initials for the project you are working on, the class name, then (sometimes) what "type" of class they are (as is the apparent convention for view controllers).

Honestly, I am right there with you Mel, I would be absolutely exhilarated for Objective-C to add some sort of namespacing feature, at least something to sort out classes a bit more (and a bit easier).

Comment: +1. Though, I'm a bad, bad boy and I prefix only classes that I bundle in a library (classes in my apps aren't usually prefixed).

Comment: Even if it's only syntactic sugar around prefixes... `@namespace Cocoa = NS; @namespace CoreAnimation = CA; Cocoa::Object *obj = [CoreAnimation::Transition animation];` anybody?

Comment: @zneak Yeah, I only prefix classes that I plan to reuse elsewhere. If its staying in that particular app, then I'll settle for simplicity, thank you. @Jonathan The prefixes, themselves, don't bother me. I just would rather have at least a minimal amount of namespacing. Even un-nestable namespaces would be awesome (one tier deep). That would even avoid the .NET namespace soup!